# WPF Extended Toolkit - CheckComboBox SelectedValue Ordering

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I'm having the situation where when I check items in the combo box it orders the comma delimited selectedvalue according to the order of the items in the drop down. So for example.

If I have the following dropdown:

```
[] A
[] B 
[] C
```

And I then go ahead and first tick B then C and then A. The selectedvalue then shows A,B,C and not B,C,A. Which means that for some reason the values are being sorted after selection.  From tests it seems to sort the comma delimited selectedvalue to be in the same order as the order they appear in the dropdown. How can I disable this so that it doesn't sort the selectedvalue? I want to have the selected value read B,C,A in the order I selected them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I seemed to discover my problem minutes after I made the post. I had the IsAsync attribute set to true on the binding of my SelectedValue and for some reason this caused the SelectedValue to be ordered. Not sure why though, but as soon as I removed the IsAsync=True everything was normal.

Was:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Occurrence.Appointment.SelectedRows, Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True}" >
```

Now:

```
SelectedValue="{Binding Occurrence.Appointment.SelectedRows, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Hope this helps someone someday with similar problem.